# How to create DOM element on event, and then prevent event handler from triggering until DOM element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So basically I'm creating a tooltip function.

And tooltip will appear as a new DOM element over the element you clicked.

Here is the fiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltipTarget').click(function () {
        var title = $(this).data('tooltip');

        $('<p class="tooltip active"></p>')
            .text(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn(250);

        var coords = $(this).offset();
        var tooltipHeight = $('.tooltip').height() + $(this).height() + 20;
        var tooltipWidth = $('.tooltip').width() / 2;

        coords.top = coords.top - tooltipHeight;
        coords.left = coords.left - tooltipWidth;

        $('.tooltip').css({
            top: coords.top,
            left: coords.left
        });

    });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: #767676;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 10;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<button style="margin: 50px;" data-tooltip="This is a tooltip" class="tooltipTarget">Click me!</button>
```

But the problem I have is that new DOM elements will keep appearing as long as you trigger the event.

I wont to prevent it. I want it to be like this:

1)You click a button

2)Tooltip appears

3)You click again on the button - tooltip disappears.

How can I do it?

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4d8xhLqj/2/

Comment: If you create a new tool tip element every time, your page is going to be littered with hidden paragraph tags. Why not just use one element, and move it to the desired location on click?

Comment: I would second what @JamesSutherland has put. The tooltip should pre-exist so you only have to play with its positioning and opacity later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would second what @JamesSutherland has put. The tooltip should pre-exist so you only have to play with its positioning and opacity later on.

Having said that though, if you really need to follow the approach that you already have, you could do this:

***Snippet:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltipTarget').click(function() {
    var title = $(this).data('tooltip');
    if (!$('p.tooltip').hasClass('active')) {
      $('<p class="tooltip active"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn(250);
      var coords = $(this).offset();
      var tooltipHeight = $('.tooltip').height() + $(this).height() + 20;
      var tooltipWidth = $('.tooltip').width() / 2;
      coords.top = coords.top - tooltipHeight;
      coords.left = coords.left - tooltipWidth;
      $('.tooltip').css({
        top: coords.top,
        left: coords.left
      });
    } else {
      $('p.tooltip.active').fadeOut(250, function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1px;
  color: #767676;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 10;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="margin: 200px;" data-tooltip="This is a tooltip" class="tooltipTarget">Click me!</button>
```

Here is the **[resulting fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4d8xhLqj/4/)**. Hope this helps.

Comment: Another small question, how can I remove the element if I click anywhere outside of it, not only on the element with the trigger?

Comment: you would listen to a `click` event on the whole of document and you would check if the `e.target` of the click event is _not_ the `.tooltipTarget` object. If it is not, you would forcefully `.trigger()` the click on `.toolTipTarget` object, which would then `.fadeOut()` the element and remove the `click` event on the `document` object. Take a look at **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/4d8xhLqj/5/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the tooltip is already shown:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltipTarget').click(function () {
        var title = $(this).data('tooltip');
        if ($('.tooltip[data-title=' + title + ']').length > 0) {
            $('.tooltip[data-title=' + title + ']').remove();
            return;
        } 
        $('<p class="tooltip active" data-title=" ' + title + ' "></p>')
            .text(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn(250);

        var coords = $(this).offset();
        var tooltipHeight = $('.tooltip').height() + $(this).height() + 20;
        var tooltipWidth = $('.tooltip').width() / 2;

        coords.top = coords.top - tooltipHeight;
        coords.left = coords.left - tooltipWidth;

        $('.tooltip').css({
            top: coords.top,
            left: coords.left
        });

    });
});
```

I've added a data attribute to the newly created tooltip in order to check afterwards if there is a tooltip for that element present, and if yes, remove it and return.

Answer (score 0):

just check whether or not the tooltip exists as part of your click function. Remove the tooltip when it does exist and create a tooltip when it doesn't.

```
if($('.tooltip').length) {
  $('.tooltip').remove();
}
else {
  //create the tooltip as usual here
}
```

here is a working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4d8xhLqj/3/